# Website is not working on mobiles

Tags: php

I have developed a eCommerce kind of website and hosted on sever, when i am accessing my website(www.myhappybox.in) through laptop or desktop it is working very finely but when i am accessing through mobile browser it is working properly the website is being distorted.  Can you guys Please help me what can be done so that my website www.myhappybox.in will work smoothly on mobile browser?

Comment: you haven't say anything about the problems, what happens? resolutions problem or something about the behaviour of the page?

Comment: Is your website is [responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) ? Also highlight what you have tried to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

your website is not responsive as shown in the pic. To resolve phone, tablet, etc screen issues it must be responsive to every screen size. You have two options:

1. you can use a lot of CSS
2. you can save typing by following famous bootstrap framework[image]